# Find all numbers with the specified difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table with rows and variable a=3. I want to find all numbers with difference >=3. At the first step, I need to take the first line, then find the next one where the difference will be > = a (3). This is 5. Then 12. Now from 12 it is necessary to find the nearest line where the difference will be >= a (3). It's 15 and so on. I want to get the final table with numbers: 1, 5, 12, 15, 20, 30

```
|number|
|------|
| 1    |
| 5    |
| 12   |
| 13   |
| 14   | 
| 15   |
| 20   |
| 21   |
| 30   |
```

Comment: Why is 21 not included in the expected output, given that it's lead number is 30, whose difference is greater than 3?

Comment: Please better explain the logic, by editing your question (and not via more comments).

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join:

```
select a.number
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.number <= a.number + 3
  and a.number < b.number
where b.number is null
```

This only selects rows from `a` that *don't* join to a number that's greater than a.number, but less than a.number + 3

Slightly less code, but perhaps more obtuse:

```
select a.number
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.number - a.number between 1 and 3
where b.number is null
```

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thank you very much. 
select distinct a.number
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.number >= a.number - 3
  and a.number > b.number
where b.number is null or a.number-b.number>=3